# What version of NgRx can I use with Angular 4

Tags: angular, ngrx

Is the latest version of NgRx/store, specifically NgRx compatible with Angular 4? If not, what version of NgRx do I need to use with Angular 4?

Also, is NgRx/store 4 vastly different from version 6? For example, if I learn version 6, will I have trouble transitioning to 4?

Sorry if this question is too basic, I couldn't find an answer to this with google.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that the versioning of ngrx has been mirroring that of angular. So if you check out ngrx v4.1.1 you'll notice it has a dependency of angular 4. I think the same is true of ngrx 5.x and 6.x. So it seems to me you should probably be safe with ngrx 4.x

https://github.com/ngrx/platform/tree/v4.1.1

Comment: Awesome! I appreciate it. Do you have an opinion on whether there are major differences between 4 & 6? All the learning material seems to be for 6, and I have to use 4 for my project. Thanks again

Comment: 4 and 6 are fairly similar, but if you ever get stuck just add `angular 4` to the end of your search

Comment: The "only" big change that impacts your development is the use of RxJS. Angular 6 uses RxJS 6, which introduces tree-shakable operators and pipeable operators.